# Circular dependency in composition root

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, dependency-inversion, circular-dependency

I have a MDI *MyMDIWinForm* that needs an instance of *IGUIErrorHanlder* for error handling, At the same time *IGUIErrorHanlder* depends on the MDI *MyMDIWinForm* for having a place from where to launch pop-ups and other stuff.

```
public class MyMDIWinForm 
{
   readonly IGUIErrorHanlder  GUIErrorHandler;
   public MyMDIWinForm(IGUIErrorHanlder guiErrorHandler)
   {
       GUIErrorHandler=guiErrorHandler;
   }

   public void DumbMethod()
   {
     try
     {
        //dumb code
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         GUIErrorHandler.OnError(e.Message);
     }
   }

}

public FormGUIErrorHanlder:IGUIErrorHanlder
{
     readonly  Form Parent;
     public FormGUIErrorHanlder(Form form)
     {
         //this form should be the MDI form
         Parent=form;
     }

     public OnError(string message)
     {
          Parent.ShowDialog(new PopUpForm(message));
     }
}
```

I want that *MyMDIWinForm* has a instance of *FormGUIErrorHanlder* and that *FormGUIErrorHanlder* has the same instance of *MyMDIWinForm*

How do I remove that circular dependency?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't get it. I don't see `MyWinForm` in `FormGUIErrorHanlder`. I just see it using some form that could be any form. If there is a circular dependency here it isn't a static one. Maybe pass it some other form?

Comment: Wait 1 min i edit the question

Comment: @candied_orange sorry because you take your time to read my question. But i can solve t by creating a factory of IGUIErrorHandler. If you are right i will delete the question

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(object-oriented_programming))?

```
public class MyMDIWinForm 
{
   ...

   public void DumbMethod()
   {
     try
     {
        //dumb code
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         GUIErrorHandler.OnError(this, e.Message);
     }
   }

}

public FormGUIErrorHanlder:IGUIErrorHanlder
{
     ...

     public OnError(Form parentForm, string message)
     {
          parentForm.ShowDialog(new PopUpForm(message));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution here is to not have the constructor injection in FormGUIErrorHandler. Instead, have an extra parameter in OnError of type Form and pass in the form from the MyMDIWinForm class.

The key here is that the dependency you were trying to model is actually too tight. The FormGUIErrorHandler class should be able to deal with any Form. You might even want to consider having only one IGUIErrorHandler in your application.

Comment: If i pass a Form type parameter to the IGUIErrorHandler I am in front of a leak implementation

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved by injecting a factory:

```
 public interface  IErrorGUIHandlerFactory
 {
        IErrorGUIHandler Create(Form form);
 }



public class MyMDIWinForm 
{
   readonly IErrorGUIHandlerFactory GUIErrorHandlerFactory;

   public MyMDIWinForm(IErrorGUIHandlerFactory guiErrorHandlerFact)
   {
       GUIErrorHandlerFactory=guiErrorHandlerFact;
   }

   public void DumbMethod()
   {
     try
     {
        //dumb code
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         //use the factory passing Form as parameter
         GUIErrorHandlerFactory.Create(this).OnError(e.Message);
     }
   }

}
```